# How to pass extra property to a children element in a reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-router-v4

This is my goal. I want to create a composite component which will check the validity of the matched url before showing the `children` element.  Otherwise it return a common component to show an error message.

So here is my code of my 'decorator':

```
const EnforceUrlValidation = (test, children) => {
  const fn = ({ match }) => {
    if (! test( match )) {
      return ( <InvalidUrlContainer /> );
    }
    return ({children});
  }
  return fn;
}
```

It is how it is used in my router:

```
const WelcomePage = EnforceUrlValidation(
    (match) => {
      const articleId = match.params.articleId;
      return articleId && isValidarticleId(articleId);
    }
  , <WelcomeContainer/>
)
...
<Routers>
     <Switch>
          <Route
              path="/:articleId"
              component={WelcomePage}
           />
...

</Routers>
```

The problem I have now is that I still want to pass the `match` object into the `children` inside `EnforceUrlValidation`. How can I achieve that?

**Attempt 1**:

```
const EnforceUrlValidation = (test, children) => {
  const fn = ({ match }) => {
    if (! test( match )) {
      return ( <InvalidUrlContainer /> );
    }
    return (<children match={match} />);
  }
  return fn;
}
```

The `children` is not rendered in this case.

**Attempt 2**:

```
const EnforceUrlValidation = (test, children) => {
  const fn = ({ match }) => {
    if (! test( match )) {
      return ( <InvalidUrlContainer /> );
    }
    return (
      <div match={match} >{children} </div>
    )
  }
  return fn;
}
```

It fails because `div` does not support `match`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `React.cloneElement` to add property to children:

```
const EnforceUrlValidation = (test, children) => {
  const fn = ({ match }) => {
    if (! test( match )) {
      return ( <InvalidUrlContainer /> );
    }
    const extendedChild = React.cloneElement(children, {match: match});
    return extendedChild;
  }
  return fn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! FYI, the return statement can simply be `return extendedChild;` (without the enclosing parenthesises)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) You're right, thanks! answer updated.

Comment: Just a quick one: after cloning, will the `children` be garbage collected? is there any catch in term of memory usage?

Comment: Yes, GC will take care of this. Please note that  `children` (and all React elements) are just simple JS objects - React reads these objects and uses them to construct the DOM (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects).  `cloneElement` internally just creates new element object with shallowly merged props. You copy objects many times in any application and it doesn't cause memory problems so no worry here.